# AVL Tree in C Criticism

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have made an AVL tree in C and coded the basic functionality of insertion, deletion, and search. I would love some criticism on my implementation especially on the insertion and deletion section of the code. Furthermore I think I could have used one less variable in the Node structure as you do not need a height for both the left and the right sub-tree instead you just need to know their balance, but for now the implementation contains the height for the left and right sub-tree.

TLDR - Criticism on my implementation of the AVL Tree especially the insertion and deletion section of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(x, y) (x < y ? y : x)

struct Node
{
   void *data;
   int32_t max_height_left;
   struct Node *left;
   int32_t max_height_right;
   struct Node *right;
};

struct AVL_Tree
{
   struct Node *root;
   size_t size_of_data;
   int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *);
   void (*print)(const void *);
};

int32_t create_tree(struct AVL_Tree **tree, const size_t size_of_data, int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *), void (*print)(const void *))
{
   *tree = malloc(sizeof(**tree));
   if(*tree == NULL)
   {
      return -1;
   }
   (*tree)->size_of_data = size_of_data;
   (*tree)->compare = compare;
   (*tree)->print = print;
   return 0;
}

static struct Node * left_rotate(struct Node *node)
{
   struct Node *temp;
   temp = node->right;

   node->right = temp->left;
   node->max_height_right = temp->max_height_left;

   temp->left = node;
   temp->max_height_left = MAX(node->max_height_left, node->max_height_right) + 1;
   return temp;
}

static struct Node * right_rotate(struct Node *node)
{
   struct Node *temp;
   temp = node->left;

   node->left = temp->right;
   node->max_height_left = temp->max_height_right;

   temp->right = node;
   temp->max_height_right = MAX(node->max_height_left, node->max_height_right) + 1;
   return temp;
}

static struct Node * insert_data_helper(struct Node *node, const void *data, int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *), const size_t size_of_data)
{
   struct Node *temp;
   int32_t results;
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      /*allocate all the memory*/
      temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
      if(temp == NULL)
      {
         return NULL;
      }
      temp->data = malloc(size_of_data);
      if(temp->data == NULL)
      {
         free(temp);
         return NULL;
      }

      /*set all the vars*/
      memcpy(temp->data, data, size_of_data);
      temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
      temp->max_height_left = temp->max_height_right = 0;
      return temp;
   }

   results = compare(data, node->data);
   if(results < 0)
   {
      node->left = insert_data_helper(node->left, data, compare, size_of_data);

      /*get the greater of the two heights from the left sub tree*/
      node->max_height_left = MAX(node->left->max_height_left, node->left->max_height_right) + 1;

      if(node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right > 1)
      {
         if(node->left->max_height_left - node->left->max_height_right <= -1)
         {
            node->left = left_rotate(node->left);
         }
         node = right_rotate(node);
      }
   }
   else if(results > 0)
   {
      node->right = insert_data_helper(node->right, data, compare, size_of_data);

      /*get the greater of the two heights from the right sub tree*/
      node->max_height_right = MAX(node->right->max_height_left, node->right->max_height_right) + 1;

      if(node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right < -1)
      {
         if(node->right->max_height_left - node->right->max_height_right >= 1)
         {
            node->right = right_rotate(node->right);
         }
         node = left_rotate(node);
      }
   }

   return node;
}

void insert_data(struct AVL_Tree *tree, const void *data)
{
   tree->root = insert_data_helper(tree->root, data, tree->compare, tree->size_of_data);
}

static struct Node * get_lowest_value_node(struct Node *node)
{
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return NULL;
   }
   else if(node->left == NULL)
   {
      return node;
   }

   return get_lowest_value_node(node->left);
}

/*delete data*/
static struct Node * delete_data_helper(struct Node *node, const void *data, int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *), const size_t size_of_data)
{
   struct Node *temp;
   int32_t results;

   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return NULL;
   }

   results = compare(data, node->data);
   if(results < 0)
   {
      node->left = delete_data_helper(node->left, data, compare, size_of_data);
      node->max_height_left = node->left == NULL ? 0 : MAX(node->left->max_height_left, node->left->max_height_right) + 1;

      if(node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right < -1)
      {
         if(node->right != NULL && node->right->max_height_left - node->right->max_height_right >= 1)
         {
            node->right = right_rotate(node->right);
         }
         node = left_rotate(node);
      }
   }
   else if(results > 0)
   {
      node->right = delete_data_helper(node->right, data, compare, size_of_data);
      node->max_height_right = node->right == NULL ? 0 : MAX(node->right->max_height_left, node->right->max_height_right) + 1;

      if(node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right > 1)
      {
         if(node->left != NULL && node->left->max_height_left - node->left->max_height_right <= -1)
         {
            node->left = left_rotate(node->left);
         }
         node = right_rotate(node);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if(node->left == NULL)
      {
         temp = node->right;
         free(node->data);
         free(node);
         return temp;
      }
      else if(node->right == NULL)
      {
         temp = node->left;
         free(node->data);
         free(node);
         return temp;
      }
      else
      {
         /*has two branches. get the lowest value from the right branch*/
         temp = get_lowest_value_node(node->right);
         memcpy(node->data, temp->data, size_of_data);

         /*now delete the value that was copies from the right branch*/
         node->right = delete_data_helper(node->right, temp->data, compare, size_of_data);
         node->max_height_right = node->right == NULL ? 0 : MAX(node->right->max_height_left, node->right->max_height_right) + 1;

         if(node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right > 1)
         {
            if(node->left != NULL && node->left->max_height_left - node->left->max_height_right <= -1)
            {
               node->left = left_rotate(node->left);
            }
            node = right_rotate(node);
         }
      }
   }

   return node;
}

void delete_data(struct AVL_Tree *tree, const void *data)
{
   tree->root = delete_data_helper(tree->root, data, tree->compare, tree->size_of_data);
}

static int8_t contains_data_helper(struct Node *node, const void *data, int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *))
{
   int32_t results;
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   results = compare(data, node->data);
   if(results < 0)
   {
      return contains_data_helper(node->left, data, compare);
   }
   else if(results > 0)
   {
      return contains_data_helper(node->right, data, compare);
   }

   return 0;
}

int8_t contains_data(struct AVL_Tree *tree, const void *data)
{
   return contains_data_helper(tree->root, data, tree->compare);
}

static void free_tree_helper(struct Node *node)
{
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return;
   }

   free_tree_helper(node->left);
   free_tree_helper(node->right);

   free(node->data);
   free(node);
}

void free_tree(struct AVL_Tree *tree)
{
   free_tree_helper(tree->root);
}

static void pre_order_helper(struct Node *node, void (*print)(const void *))
{
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return;
   }
   print(node->data);
   printf("(left = %d, right = %d, balance = %d)\n", node->max_height_left, node->max_height_right, node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right);
   pre_order_helper(node->left, print);
   pre_order_helper(node->right, print);
}

void pre_order(struct AVL_Tree *tree)
{
   pre_order_helper(tree->root, tree->print);
}

static void in_order_helper(struct Node *node, void (*print)(const void *))
{
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return;
   }
   in_order_helper(node->left, print);
   print(node->data);
   printf("(left = %d, right = %d, balance = %d)\n", node->max_height_left, node->max_height_right, node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right);
   in_order_helper(node->right, print);
}

void in_order(struct AVL_Tree *tree)
{
   in_order_helper(tree->root, tree->print);
}

static void post_order_helper(struct Node *node, void (*print)(const void *))
{
   if(node == NULL)
   {
      return;
   }
   post_order_helper(node->left, print);
   post_order_helper(node->right, print);
   print(node->data);
   printf("(left = %d, right = %d, balance = %d)\n", node->max_height_left, node->max_height_right, node->max_height_left - node->max_height_right);
}

void post_order(struct AVL_Tree *tree)
{
   post_order_helper(tree->root, tree->print);
}

/*user code*/

void print_data(const void *ptr)
{
   const int *ptr_temp = ptr;
   printf("%d ", *ptr_temp);
}

int compare(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
   const int *ptr1_temp, *ptr2_temp;
   ptr1_temp = ptr1;
   ptr2_temp = ptr2;

   if(*ptr1_temp < *ptr2_temp)
   {
      return -1;
   }
   else if(*ptr1_temp > *ptr2_temp)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   struct AVL_Tree *tree;
   int i;

   /*array is used to insert data into the tree*/
   int array[] = {1, 2, 3};

   create_tree(&tree, sizeof(array[0]), &compare, &print_data);

   for(i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); i++)
   {
      insert_data(tree, (array + i));
   }

   pre_order(tree);
   printf("\n\n\n");

   i = 3;
   delete_data(tree, &i);

   pre_order(tree);

   i = 1;
   printf("\n(Contains the value %d) = %d(0 == yes, -1 == no)\n", i, contains_data(tree, &i));

   free_tree(tree);
   return 0;
}
```

This is the make file I use

```
program: BBST.o
        gcc *.o -o program

BBST.o: BBST.c
        gcc -g -c -Wall -pedantic BBST.c

clean:
        rm *.o program
```

Comment: I would look at a way to rename the functions a little bit - all your main functions are calling a corresponding `helper` function, which feels too generic and vague. Helping with what? Also, why have these helpers if the main functions are going to be one-liners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Height**

The usually AVL tree needs to only record the height difference or [balance factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Balance_factor): [-1, 0, 1].  Instead of 2 `int32_t`.  A `signed char` will do.  Given `struct` alignment issue, might as well use a single `int`.

**Naming**

Instead of global names all over the name space as with:

```
struct Node
struct AVL_Tree
create_tree()
insert_data()
delete_data()
free_tree()
...
```

How about a uniform style and prefix?

```
struct AVL_Node
struct AVL_Tree
AVL_create()
AVL_insert()
AVL_delete()
AVL_free()
AVL_...
```

**AVL.h**

I'd really like to see `AVL.c, AVL.h, main.c` for a clear demarcation of what is seen by the public and what is private.

**Fixed width types**

Rather than `int32_t`, consider an `int`.  `int32_t` is excessively wide for small applications.

**C2X ordering**

Consider [the order of parameters in function declarations should be arranged such that the size of an array appears before the array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features).
Wrap long lines.

```
// static struct Node * insert_data_helper(struct Node *node, const void *data, int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *), const size_t size_of_data);
static struct Node *insert_data_helper(size_t size, struct Node *node, void *data, 
    int32_t (*compare)(const void *, const void *));
```

**Allocate to the referenced object**

Good use of  `*tree = malloc(sizeof(**tree));`

**Minor: Unneeded `else`**

```
if (node == NULL) {
  return NULL;
}
// else if(node->left == NULL) {
if (node->left == NULL) {
  return node;
}
```

Also in `contains_data_helper()`.

**Good to tolerate `delete_data_helper(NULL, ...)`**

Also `free_tree_helper(NULL)`.

**Consider a return value on the helper function**

Instead of `void (*f)(const void *)`, how about `int (*f)(const void *)` that returns early when the return value is non-zero.

```
static int helper(struct Node *node, int (*foo)(const void *)) {
   if(node == NULL) {
      return 0;
   }
   int retval = helper(node->left, print);
   if (retval) {
     return retval;
   }
   retval = foo(node->data);
   if (retval) {
     return retval;
   }
   return helper(node->right, foo);
}
```

I'd even consider passing in a `state`.

```
static int helper(struct Node *node, 
    int (*foo)(void * state, const void *), void *state);
```

---

> Criticism on my implementation of the AVL Tree especially the insertion and deletion section of the code.

A better than usual AVL code.
Good to properly `free(temp);` on insertion failure.